# Taylor expansions on manifolds..

Tags: geometry, analysis, manifolds

can one consider Taylor expansions of functions defined between smooth manifolds? If so, is there a reference for learning more about it? Thanks

Comment: differential geometry

Comment: you answer is too general..

Comment: It precisely answers your question though.

Comment: ok, could you be a bit more specific?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed you can.

If you have $\operatorname{f} : M^m \to N^n$ then *locally* this is just a map $\mathbb{R}^m \to \mathbb{R}^n$.

If $\operatorname{f}(x)=y$ then we phrase the local situation in terms of "germs" $\operatorname{f} : (M,x) \to (N,y)$ and "jets".

One famous reference is "*[Stable mappings and their singularities](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Stable-Mappings-Singularities-Graduate-Mathematics/dp/038790073X)*" by Golubitsky & Guillemin.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check the reference..